# Pytorch does not update weight after optimizer.step()

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network

I'm coding Neural Network with Pytorch but i have a prolem. Pytorch does not update weight after optimizer.step().
This is my code:
Neuralnetwork.py

```
import torch

class NeuralNetwork(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,
                 size_of_hidden_layer:tuple=(5, 5)
                 ) -> None:
        super().__init__()

        self.number_of_hidden_layers = size_of_hidden_layer[0]
        self.number_of_node_each_hidden_layers = size_of_hidden_layer[1]

        self.hidden_layers = None
        
        self.setActFunc('relu')
    
    def fit(self, X, y):
        if self.hidden_layers != None:
            return
        
        self.hidden_layers = torch.nn.ModuleList()
        self.hidden_layers.append(torch.nn.Linear(in_features=X.shape[1], 
                                                  out_features=self.number_of_node_each_hidden_layers))
        for _ in range(self.number_of_hidden_layers-1):
            self.hidden_layers.append(torch.nn.Linear(in_features=self.number_of_node_each_hidden_layers, 
                                               out_features=self.number_of_node_each_hidden_layers))
            
        self.output = torch.nn.Linear(in_features=self.number_of_node_each_hidden_layers, 
                                         out_features=y.shape[1])
        
        
    def setActFunc(self, act_func:str):
        if act_func == 'relu':
            self.activation = torch.nn.ReLU()
        if act_func == 'leaky':
            self.activation = torch.nn.LeakyReLU()
        if act_func == 'sigmoid':
            self.activation = torch.nn.Sigmoid()

    def forward(self, X):
        A = X
        for layer in self.hidden_layers:
            Z = layer(A)
            A = self.activation(Z)

        Z = self.output(A)
        y = torch.nn.Sigmoid()(Z)

        return (y >= 0.5) * 1.0
```

Trainer.py

```
import torch
from torch.nn import Module, MSELoss
from torch.optim import SGD, Adam

class Trainer():
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass

    def train(self, model:Module, X:torch.Tensor, y:torch.Tensor, epochs=10, lr=0.01, act_func='relu'):
        train_model = model
        train_model.setActFunc(act_func)
        train_model.fit(X, y)
        optimizer = Adam(params=train_model.parameters(), lr=lr)
        loss_func = MSELoss()

        for epoch in range(epochs):
            train_model.train()

            optimizer.zero_grad()

            pred = train_model(X)
            loss = loss_func(pred.squeeze(), y.squeeze())

            loss.requires_grad = True
            loss.backward()

            optimizer.step()
```

main.py

```
import torch
import NeuralNetwork as NN
import Trainer
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__':
    torch.random.manual_seed(42)

    # Create data
    sample = 10
    feature = 100
    X = torch.rand(size=(sample, feature), requires_grad=True) * 10
    y = (torch.rand(size=(sample, 1), requires_grad=True) >= 0.5).type(torch.float)

    # Check if model work
    model = NN.NeuralNetwork(size_of_hidden_layer=(1, 15))
    model.fit(X, y)
    
    # Check weight before train
    print(model.state_dict())

    # Train model
    trainer = Trainer.Trainer()
    trainer.train(model, X=X, y=y, epochs=1000)
    
    # Check weight after train
    print(model.state_dict())
```

When i run the file main.py, then the result is:

```
Before train:
OrderedDict([('hidden_layers.0.weight', tensor([[ 0.0260, -0.0809, -0.0605,  ...,  0.0265, -0.0153,  0.0411],
        [-0.0417, -0.0943, -0.0384,  ..., -0.0058,  0.0766,  0.0625],
        [ 0.0919, -0.0732,  0.0643,  ..., -0.0694,  0.0010,  0.0003],
        ...,
        [ 0.0034,  0.0239, -0.0124,  ..., -0.0813, -0.0271,  0.0883],
        [ 0.0391, -0.0119,  0.0206,  ..., -0.0621, -0.0815,  0.0218],
        [-0.0551,  0.0284,  0.0847,  ..., -0.0059,  0.0009, -0.0260]])), ('hidden_layers.0.bias', tensor([-0.0683,  0.0907, -0.0331,  0.0477,  0.0696, -0.0657, -0.0125,  0.0578,
         0.0969, -0.0126,  0.0725, -0.0785, -0.0650,  0.0822, -0.0095])), ('output.weight', tensor([[ 0.2551,  0.0188, -0.1071,  0.2452,  0.2258,  0.0240, -0.1565, -0.0112,
         -0.1242,  0.1881,  0.0120,  0.0544,  0.1566,  0.0855, -0.1612]])), ('output.bias', tensor([0.2145]))])

After train:
OrderedDict([('hidden_layers.0.weight', tensor([[ 0.0260, -0.0809, -0.0605,  ...,  0.0265, -0.0153,  0.0411],
        [-0.0417, -0.0943, -0.0384,  ..., -0.0058,  0.0766,  0.0625],
        [ 0.0919, -0.0732,  0.0643,  ..., -0.0694,  0.0010,  0.0003],
        ...,
        [ 0.0034,  0.0239, -0.0124,  ..., -0.0813, -0.0271,  0.0883],
        [ 0.0391, -0.0119,  0.0206,  ..., -0.0621, -0.0815,  0.0218],
        [-0.0551,  0.0284,  0.0847,  ..., -0.0059,  0.0009, -0.0260]])), ('hidden_layers.0.bias', tensor([-0.0683,  0.0907, -0.0331,  0.0477,  0.0696, -0.0657, -0.0125,  0.0578,
         0.0969, -0.0126,  0.0725, -0.0785, -0.0650,  0.0822, -0.0095])), ('output.weight', tensor([[ 0.2551,  0.0188, -0.1071,  0.2452,  0.2258,  0.0240, -0.1565, -0.0112,
         -0.1242,  0.1881,  0.0120,  0.0544,  0.1566,  0.0855, -0.1612]])), ('output.bias', tensor([0.2145]))])
```

I've searched on Internet about this, but they look somehow different with me. Anyone help me, please!

Comment: Your gradients are likely zero due to this line return (y >= 0.5) * 1.0, think about what is the gradient of this function.